# Create a UDF accept a CSV string and return a Table in DB2 to be used in a Stored Proc for Bulk Insert

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions

I am very new to Databases.. hence the question.

I need to do a bulk insert into tables. As an input to the Stored proc I get a string like shown below

```
"1, abc, 123.45; 2, def, 678.90; 3, ghi, 332.99;"
```

Is it possible to create a UDF which will return a table that looks like

```
Column 1   Column 2  Column 3
 1          abc       123.45
 2          def       678.90
 3          ghi       332.99
```

Comment: Which version of DB2?  Where's this data coming from?  How are you supposed to tell what the datatype of the column is supposed to be?  Is the data supposed to be persisted, as opposed to just a temp table?  How many rows?

Comment: DB2 version is DB2/NT64 9.1.4. The Data is coming from C++ application. 1st coulumn is int (index column) rest will be Varchar. I need to use the table in a Stored proc, but I want to be able to do some processing on it before actually storing it. Rows may be indefinite... I want to search for ";" to define the rows. and "," to define columns

Comment: Hmm, you _can_ split it up using loops, in a stored procedure, although I'd personally prefer to do it in the application layer, then block upload it to the database to a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`  If you have a really large number of rows, you could probably use the load command to just upload the whole file - you may need to reformat it slightly.

Comment: Or is it somehow possible to pass a table as a parameter to the SP where I want to do an insert? And create the table in C++ code and send it thourgh?

Comment: Thanx X-Zero, the looping and Global Temporary table worked for me the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a table function, and implementing that functionality.

I use Java to do that kind of things.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009197.html

You can also use only SQL: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0053768.html

This is an example I propose using Java:

```
public void cvsToTable(String csv/*val1*/, int val2, String val3, double val4)
        throws Exception {
switch (getCallType()) {
case SQLUDF_TF_FIRST:
    break;
case SQLUDF_TF_OPEN:
    // Creates a tokenizer or something similar
    st = new StringTokenizer(csv, ";");
    break;
case SQLUDF_TF_FETCH: // This is called each time for each row.
    // Iterates over the set of tokens (each row)
    if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String row = st.nextToken();
        StringTokenizer values = new StringTokenizer(row, ",");
        int i = 2;
        int MAX = 5;
        while (values.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String record = values.nextToken();
            if (i >= MAX) {
                i = 2
            // Sets the record in the answer.
            set(i, record);
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        // No more rows
        setSQLstate("02000");
    }
    break;
case SQLUDF_TF_CLOSE:
    break;
case SQLUDF_TF_FINAL:
    break;
default:
    throw new Exception("Unexpected call type of " + getCallType());
}
}
```

I wrote a blog that explains how to use table functions: http://angocadb2.blogspot.com/2012/02/accediendo-tweeter-desde-db2-table.html